# How to set ModelState true from controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

How to set `ModelState = true;` in asp.net MVC from controller action

as we know ModelState.IsValid is readOnly ie. holds getter only, So we can't force our modelState to true like this
`ModelState.Isvalid = true; //what we can't do`


Now do tell me guys what is the correct way to set modelsatate.isvalid to true

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could `ModelState.Clear()` it. But this will remove all errors and values. If you want to remove only the errors you could loop through all elements in the ModelState and for each element remove the errors that might be associated to it. Once you do that, `ModelState.IsValid` will become `true`.

Comment: The mentioned loop is: foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys) ModelState[key].Errors.Clear()